# Removing rows in R based on values in a single column

Tags: r

I have a n x 3 matrix in R and want to remove all rows where the last column is less than x. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could also use the `subset()` function.

```
a <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3)  
threshhold <- 8  
subset(a, a[ , 3] < threshhold)
```

Answer (score 5):

Same approach as @JeffAllen but in a little more detail and generalisable to a matrix of any size.

```
    data <- rbind(c(1,2,3), c(1, 7, 4), c(4,6,7), c(3, 3, 3), c(4, 8, 6))
    data
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    1    2    3
    [2,]    1    7    4
    [3,]    4    6    7
    [4,]    3    3    3
    [5,]    4    8    6
    #
    # set value of x
    x <- 3
    # 
    # return matrix that contains only those rows where value in 
    # the final column is greater than x. 
    # This will scale up to a matrix of any size 
    data[data[,ncol(data)]>x,]
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    1    7    4
    [2,]    4    6    7
    [3,]    4    8    6
```

Answer (score 2):

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(9), ncol=3)
m <- m[m[,3]>0,]
```

Creates a matrix, then redefines that matrix only to include those rows in which the third column is greater than 0 (`m[,3] > 0`).