# How to delete all rows in data table that contain a conserved string

Tags: r

**EDIT**: tried grepl, as in:

```
DF <- DF[!grepl("M+1", DF$Column2, fixed=TRUE),]
```

(the `fixed=TRUE` is necessary because of the "+" in the string).

**Original post**:

My data frame contains a particular column that has a wide range of factors, and I want to delete any row in which that factor contains a particular string.

For example, I want to delete rows 1 and 3 from the table below, because they contain the conserved string "M+1".

```
Column1    Column2    Column3
x          [3]M+1     y
x                     y
x          [2]M+1     y
x                     y
```

I'd be fine if the column entry was just a static string, e.g.

```
DF <- DF[!(DF$Column2 == "M+1"),]
```

But unfortunately there are other, irrelevant components to the factors in the column. I considered using `%in%` but can't figure out how to make it "not in" rather than "in". I've tried [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/in-operator-NOT-IN-td3506655.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005154/conditionally-remove-dataframe-rows-with-r), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252068/removing-rows-in-r-based-on-values-in-a-single-column) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764810/delete-rows-based-on-range-of-values-in-column) etc. but they're mainly dealing with deleting rows based on numeric values rather than factors (and based on the absolute value in the column, rather than whether it "contains" a particular value). Thanks.

Comment: Check out `?grepl` as in `grepl("M+1", DF$Column2, fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail, that looks promising, but for some reason it's not working for the "M+1" string (while it works for the "REVERSE" string as in the example you linked as duplicate).

Comment: Because `+` is a special character in regular expressions. Notice my comment above has `fixed=TRUE` - either use that or escape the `+` sign like `"M\\+1"`

Comment: I thought I'd tried that straight away but must have missed it. Thank you very much.